# Loop over strings and read in files and save

Tags: string, loops, import, sas

I am pretty new to SAS. I have a bunch of files that are in csv format that I want to read into SAS. I need to read them in one-by-one and save them, either individually or preferably in one huge file. (Although the file might be really large...not sure how to best deal with this - MySQL maybe?)

Say the file are named like this:

```
file97.csv
file98.csv
file99.csv
file00.csv
file01.csv
file02.csv
```

How can I loop over the `97, 98, 99, 00, 01, 02` in a loop statement?

If I import just, say `file97.csv`, the code is something like:

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= WORK.data97 
            DATAFILE= "\...\file97.csv" 
            DBMS=CSV REPLACE;
     GETNAMES=YES;
     DATAROW=2; 
RUN;
```

What code would I write to loop? I basically need to change only the `97`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to loop over `Proc import` you will have to `Macros` for that, also since you `Numbers 97, 98, 99, 00, 01, 02` are not consecutive you will have to use a workaround.

```
%let files=97,98,99,00,01,02;
%macro loop_over;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw("&files."));
PROC IMPORT OUT= WORK.data%sysfunc(scan("&files.",&i.,",")) 
            DATAFILE= "\...\file%sysfunc(scan("&files.",&i.,",")).csv" 
            DBMS=CSV REPLACE;
     GETNAMES=YES;
     DATAROW=2; 
RUN;
%end;
%mend;
%loop_over;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is wonderful! One little thing - does one need the semicolon at the end of the fourth line?