# How to refer to i within SAS loop

Tags: loops, sas

Say I have this code:

```
data Work.dataset;
do i = 3 to 7;
    %let mname = text;
    %let mname = &mname.i;
end;
run;
```

I want the `i` in `%let mname = &mname.i;` to refer to `i = 3 to 7` and not to the letter `i`. How can I make this happen?

The real question I am trying to get at is found here: [Loop over strings and read in files and save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540552/loop-over-strings-and-read-in-files-and-save) and I am trying to figure out a way to do this. This question was trying to tackle a part of that larger question.

Comment: What do you want to do? Can you put a bit more context, your code is not making much sense

Comment: Your real question is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `%let` in data steps, use call symput.

This works better. I hope it's what you wanted.

```
data Work.dataset;

    do i = 3 to 7;
        mname1 = 'text';
        mname2 = mname1||put(i,1.);
        call symput('mname3',mname2);
        put mname2;
        output;
    end;
run;

%put mname3=&mname3;
```